# After latest updates Scilab 5.5.2 does not start on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (amd64, AMD A4-4000 APU)

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, scilab

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on computer with `AMD A4-4000 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics` and installed Scilab 5.5.2 here from official repository (package version 5.5.2-2ubuntu3).

It worked normally on 2017-12-24, but broken by some latest update. I can post dpkg-log, but [it seems](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1357) that it MESA-related:

```
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep "status installed.*mesa"
2018-01-11 14:51:08 status installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:09 status installed libglapi-mesa:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:10 status installed libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:11 status installed libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:16 status installed libegl1-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:17 status installed libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:18 status installed libosmesa6:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:18 status installed libosmesa6:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:19 status installed libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:20 status installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:20 status installed libgles2-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-11 14:51:21 status installed mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
2018-01-12 12:24:25 status installed mesa-va-drivers:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 # <- installed after crash detection by me
```

What I tried:

- Rebooted with previous kernel 4.4.0-104-generic instead of newest 4.4.0-109-generic
- Cleared Scilab folder in $HOME

  ```
  rm ~/.Scilab -rf
  ```
- Installed `vainfo` and `mesa-va-drivers` to have normal output of `vainfo` as follows:

  ```
  $ vainfo 
  libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
  libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
  libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri   /r600_drv_video.so
  libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
  libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
  vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.0)
  vainfo: Driver version: mesa gallium vaapi
  vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
        VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
        VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
        VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
        VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
  ```
- reported [bug 1742894](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1742894) to launchpad.
- upgrading to [RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) (with `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`) does not help
- BIOS upgrading does not help.

My system information:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -A3 VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7480D] [1002:9993]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7480D] [1002:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon


$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic root=UUID=... ro splash quiet vt.handoff=7


$ glxinfo | grep -i 'direct\|vendor\|opengl'
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-109-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

In *Software & Updates* `software-properties-gtk` I have only one suggestion about installation of `amd64-microcode` package. Its installation does not help.

Do you need more details?

Comment: I have the same problem running maple2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 with graphics card Radeon Kaveri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is confirmed, that [bug exists in Debian too](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=880924).

As I wrote in [Launchpad comment 18 on bug 1742894](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1742894/comments/18).

I downgraded the following packages:

```
libegl1-mesa_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgbm1_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
libgl1-mesa-glx_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgl1-mesa-glx_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
libglapi-mesa_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libglapi-mesa_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
libgles2-mesa_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libosmesa6_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libosmesa6_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
libwayland-egl1-mesa_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
mesa-va-drivers_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
mesa-vdpau-drivers_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

manually with `dpkg -i`.

And pinned them:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-mesa
Package: libegl1-mesa:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgbm1:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libglapi-mesa:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libglapi-mesa:i386
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgles2-mesa:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libosmesa6:amd64
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libosmesa6:i386
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libwayland-egl1-mesa
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: mesa-va-drivers
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: mesa-vdpau-drivers
Pin: version 11.2.0-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

It is a temporarily fix, which works for me.

**2018-03-06 update:** the [bug 1742894](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1742894/comments/38) is fixed. Now Scilab starts normally on Xenial with AMD APU/GPU. I removed pin-file from my system.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working on Ubuntu 16.04 without downgrading any package.
I just run:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0 ; scilab $*
```

Hope it helps,

Antoine

Comment: This helped me get NASA WorldWind rendering properly in my Intellij Java project on Ubuntu 16.04 with Mesa 17.2.8 - thanks!

Comment: This helped me as well. I have a computer with Nvidia graphics, Ubuntu 16.04.5 and Scilab 6.0.1. The Scilab did not start. I have also found that adding `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` to `scilab` command line helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `~/Software` directory where I wanted to install Scilab. I put a binary file (*scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz*) in the ~/Software directory and unpacked this file. Then I run the script

```
 #!/bin/bash

 export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0 ; scilab $*
```

But the `scilab $ *` command does not work. 
This scrip works:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0 ; 
 cd ~/Software/scilab-5.5.2 ;
 ./bin/scilab
```