# Scilab 5.5.2 cannot create Java Main Class on Ubuntu 14.04. How to fix?

Tags: 14.04, java, mesa, scilab

On March 5, after months of working regularly, Scilab 5.5.2 stopped working altogether if launched from GUI.

Trying to launch from terminal, it still did not work but at least informed me that it could not create a Java Main Class, and some more details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.scilab.modules.gui.utils.ConfigManager.checkVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.scilab.modules.gui.utils.ConfigManager.createUserCopy(Unknown Source)
at org.scilab.modules.core.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

The issue also appeared in Ubuntu 16.04; I tried the fix described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/999048/627674) but it did not work.

The bug with `libjogl2` has been [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1742894/comments/38) for Ubuntu 16.04, but there is no information about the situation for Ubuntu 14.04.

Anyone can help?

I have quite a lot of scripts done in Scilab and I would hate them to become unusable.

Comment: Please write comment on aforementioned bug. Developers show be informed about your problem. I do not have 14.04 LTS with AMD APU/GPU for testing as I wrote before on [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995093/after-latest-updates-scilab-5-5-2-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-amd64-a?s=1|91.2436) about 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, I will add my comment there.